# How to find k with given mean, standard deviation and probability?

Tags: r, normal-distribution

mean = 18
standard deviation = 2.5

P(X<15) is `pnorm(15,18,2.8)`

I want to find the value k such that P(X< k)=0.2236

What should I do with R?

Comment: `qnorm(0.22336, 18,2.8)`

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you tell me how to do it if I want X< k?

Comment: The posted way is exactly how to do when X<k

Comment: I am sorry! I mean (x>k) :)

Comment: recall P(X>k) = 1-P(x<k) so you know what to do. ie `1-qnorm(0.22336, 18,2.8)` or even `qnorm(0.22336, 18,2.8,lower.tail = FALSE)`